# What does the $a$ stand for in this picture? (And some clarification)

Tags: geometry, moment-of-inertia

[image: polygon]
<sub>(source: [polygonal.de](http://lab.polygonal.de/wp-content/assets/060817/pic_0.gif))</sub>
[image: triangle]
<sub>(source: [polygonal.de](http://lab.polygonal.de/wp-content/assets/060817/pic_1.gif))</sub>

$$ I_{triangle} = \frac{b^3h-b^2ha+bha^2+bh^3}{36} $$

$$ I_{total} = \sum^n_{k=1}(I_{triangle}+Md^2)_k $$

Source is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310031336/http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=57).

I'm trying to understand the mass moment of inertia in order to create a 2d physics engine, but I haven't found much resources to go by. One I did find was the above one, but I didn't fully understand it, and wanted to make sure about a few things before going through the effort of translating it into C++.

1. I am correctly understanding that this is for the *mass* moment of inertia and not something else like the area moment of inertia right?
2. What would $a$ be when the triangle is obtuse?
3. Is my understanding that the mass moment of inertia is dependent on the pivot point accurate, and that if the pivot moved away from the center of mass I'd just need to adjust the 'd's to get the new mass moment of inertia value?

Alternatively, if anybody is aware of a simpler way of going about getting the mass moment of inertia for a polygon, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Did you find [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/finding-the-moment-of-inertia-of-a-2d-polygon.698465/)?

Comment: $a$ has to be given it cannot be computed based on $h$ and $b$ alone. there are an infinite number of obtuse triangles with the same $h$ and $b$ but different $a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am correctly understanding that this is for the mass moment of inertia and not something else like the area moment of inertia right?

No. The formula given are for the area moment of inertia. Although you can essentially use them to find the moment of inertia just by multiplying the answer, you get using this formula by the area mass density of the plate. (i.e. mass per unit area of the plate).

> What would $a$ be when the triangle is obtuse?

$a$ is the distance between the foot of perpendicular drawn from the largest angle vertex on the opposite side and any of the endpoints of that opposite side. (You can chose any of the two vertices in each case because the expression in terms of $a$ is symmetric for $a$ and $b-a$. So we do not really need to care whether the triangle is obtuse or right or acute, because we are drawing the perpendicular from the largest angle vertex, we are sure that it is going to land on the opposite side. (not outside, as you were fearing perhaps)

> Is my understanding that the mass moment of inertia is dependent on the pivot point accurate, and that if the pivot moved away from the center of mass I'd just need to adjust the 'd's to get the new mass moment of inertia value?

Yes. You would need to calculate new $d$s if you are changing the pivot. Alternatively, you can again apply the parallel axis theorem.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding 'a'. So I understand that one end of it starts from the 'h' line, but you're saying that it doesn't matter which end of the base it extends towards? Wouldn't that give two different values?

Comment: Let's say angle A is the largest angle. Then draw a perpendicular from A on the line BC. Foot of this perpendicular be P. $a$ is either PB or PC. It doesn't make difference which of these two you choose because if one is taken as $a$ then the other is $b-a$ and the formula is symmetric in $a$ and $b-a$. i.e. you can replace them with each other.

Comment: Wait, so $$ b^3h-b^2ha+bha^2+bh^3 $$ includes both 'a' and 'b-a'?

Comment: $b^3h - b^2ha + bha^2 + bh^3\ =\ b^3h + bh^3 - hb (a)(b-a)$

Comment: Some additional questions; ~~ 1) I noticed that the units for $$ I_{triangle} (length^4) $$ and $$ I_{total} (implied ~ to ~ be ~ mass * length^2) $$ are different. Does that mean that I_total is already the mass moment of inertia and that I need to multiply I_triangle by the density before putting it into the second equation? ~~ 2) Can I arrange the triangles however I want? For example [img](http://imgur.com/h5nxrax.jpg) or even [img](http://imgur.com/QgMyfX0.jpg)? ~~ 3) My end goal is to get the value needed to put into here: $$  = I * α $$ The mass moment of inertia is what I need right?

Answer (score 0):

> What would  be when the triangle is obtuse ?

### Moment of inertia in increasing order :

**Acute triangle**

$$ I_{acute} = \frac{\left(b^3h+bh^3\right)+bha^2-b^2ha}{36} 
\\=\frac{\left(b^3h+bh^3\right)+a b h (a - b)}{36} $$
for acute triangle $a < b$, so second term will be *negative*, thus $I_{acute} < I_{right}$

**Right triangle**

$a = 0$, so

$$ I_{right} = \frac{\left(b^3h+bh^3\right)}{36} $$

**Obtuse triangle**

$a \Rightarrow -a$, so

$$ I_{obtuse} = \frac{\left(b^3h+bh^3\right)+bha^2+b^2ha}{36} $$

**EDIT**

For better understanding of $a$ parameter - picture of all triangle types with their corresponding $a$ parameter:

[image]